# selecting input labels not in a <label> tag in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to select basically the "label" of an input that is not enclosed in a label tag. I would like to style the values of radio button options in an HTML form. For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other  
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

In the above example, how would I select the "Male", "Female" and "Other" labels beside each button to style in CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: It is not possible with CSS alone you'll have to use JavaScript or jQuery for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the label in `<span>` or `<div>` rather than a `<lable>`. The way that it is currently laid out doesn't have any tags. Without a selector, you have nothing to point to in the CSS.

[CSS Syntax and Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp)